# How to convert web scraping python project into desktop application?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have created a web scraping project in python with the help of beautiful soup but i want my project to work as a desktop application.
So, that i can run that application and can perform web scraping on a specific url.

Is it possible using python and beautiful soup or i have to make the project in different language?

Comment: Try using a package "tkinter"

Answer (score 0):

Desktop application is basically an eye-candy layer over your code. In my eyes you have a few options:

1. Use [tkinter](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/) or PyQt: If you want to stay within the python ecosystem.
2. User [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/docs) or nw.js: Allows you to create GUI with HTML and CSS, and you can respond to events (e.g. button click) by spawning child processes. The child processes will be your scraping code. You may need to convert the existing script to a version where the inputs are given as command line arguments.

Note: I am only adding links to the ones I have used personally.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is how to turn it into an executable you can download `pyinstaller`.

If you want to build a GUI you have a few options:

1. Use a python module like: `pygame`, `tkinter`, `PyQt5`, `wxPython`, `BeeWare`.
2. Use an JavaScript framework like `electron.js`.
3. Make a Web-App and use python as a back end with a framework like `Flask` or `Django`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using ElectronJS (check out electronjs.org).

If you are proficient enough in HTML/CSS and some Javascript, you can use those markup languages to easily create a UI (which you would do on a normal website), which would look much better than any interface made using Python GUI libraries (such as `tkinter`, `pygame` etc.).

The Electron app itself is a browser but it works as a desktop application. It is also cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using fbs project with great success for exactly the same purpose. It is super simple to use, has built in support for PyQt5 and PySide2. By using it and PySide2 I've created several applications that are successfully running under both windows and Linux distributions without leaving python ecosystem. The only downside so far, only python 3.6 is officially supported. Please, take a look.
https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial